# Why do I keep receiving blank texts from a specific contact that they are NOT sending?

Tags: sms

My mom and I have been texting all day and for quite some time I thought my mom was horsing around with me and beating around the bush to tell me something. I noticed though that it kept happening even afterwards during normal conversation. I started to become annoyed and ask her what the heck she kept sending me the blank messages for and HOW because I also had noticed my phone won't even show the send button until I start to type characters not just space. She then thought I was pulling one over on her now. Just imagine the conversation okay. Haha. I took a screenshot to show her and to her surprise , on my phone it shows her sending me umteen blank text messages in-between her real ones. BUT they aren't coming from her nor are they on her phone either. Weird right ? Right.

Comment: Are you sure the messages are sent as SMS (not as RCS or using a different messenger?)? Could a problem with the sending SMS app. In case of SMS larger than 160 characters, they have to be split up into multiple SMS, may be the sending SMS app has a defect split algorithm and i the end sends one full SMS and one empty?

Comment: We might need to know both your and your mom's device model and SMS operator since they might affect the behavior, e.g. [Receiving Chinese blocks of texts in the Messaging app](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/159832/44325), [String of jumbled text is appended to every incoming SMS with Project Fi](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/172410/44325), [Broken OTP SMS on Xiaomi](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/237360/44325)