# Broken OTP SMS on Xiaomi

Tags: sms, xiaomi

I have a Xiaomi Mi Max 3 phone. Recently, I changed my app for SMS to "Messenger for messages" from "Messaging" that is, I assume, the app from Xiaomi.

For the login of Dropbox or a Credit Card, I usually receive an SMS from a foreign country (I am living in Israel) and the message, instead of e.g. a six-digit number, is this:

[image]

For SMS from my country, e.g. to enter in gov. sites with an SMS code, it works fine.

After reading in the comments about the possibility that the problem is linked to the app, I deleted Messenger for messages, and the messages I receive are the same. Here are sample SMSes from Dropbox:

> - ?,§ieKAF§IKAHKAf?ÅWK'såW¥2;#KC+s$Φövv.ùRü.Ψw.Å
> - ?,§ieKAF§IKAHKAf?ÅWK'såW¥Φ+3#;s$Φövv.ùRü.Ψw.Å
> - ?,§ieKAF§IKAHKAf?ÅWK'såW¥Φ+KΓs$Φövv.ùRü.Ψw.Å
> - ?,§ieKAF§IKAHKAf?ÅWK'såW¥2;K#Cs$Φövv.ùRü.Ψw.Å

When the expected SMS is like

> Your security code is `[6-digit code]`. Happy Dropboxing!

<sup>[Screenshot of the SMSes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC62V.jpg)</sup>

And here is a sample SMS from Amazon:

> ?PiiaguÜÜBÄCu§ÑÑF§Ä§B§F§d§ΣQQaΦsrl$a¤#Qekm¤æ-GìKìM§ΩΛ$ÄCu§Ñu¡(KÑiCiSmKAHKAFQCÑOKÄKÑiAHKAZ§iAHKA¿CggKAHKA(¥Y¡ΦΘÑ¡$aaksKuAfkeAXKAXSKÑA¿§keAda§ÑIeKÑ

When the expected SMS is like

> `[6-digit code]` is your Amazon OTP. Do not share it with anyone.

I came back to the regular SMS app for the Xiaomi phone and the problem wasn't solved. I contacted my telephone operator and they say that if an SMS is received, it's not a problem related to them. They have nothing to do with the content of the messages.  I contacted the support team of Dropbox, and they weren't able up to day to understand what is the problem. I am very surprised. I have also uninstalled and reinstalled the dual identification and the problem remained.

Maybe relevant:

- My new phone is a Xiaomi Poco F3, I use the Google SMS App and the problem is the same.
- I missed to acknowledge that I am living in Israel, my phone operator is we4G.
- I still have the problem with the bank CIC that sends SMS from France, Dropbox, and Amazon, not with Google and GitHub.
- Dropbox and Amazon weren't able to explain the phenomenon, neither my phone operator.

My question is what can I do to repair it?

Comment: Have you ever received a valid SMS before? If so, is it in English, or foreign (e.g. Hebrew) language?

Comment: @Andrew of course, along many years.

Comment: A message in English

Comment: Was there a reason you changed the SMS app? May be it is just a bug in the SMS app. There are other good SMS/messenger apps available, I would recommend e.g. Signal as messenger+SMS app.

Comment: @Robert despite I came back to the first app, the default app for this phone, the problem remained.

Comment: I can think of 2 possibilities: 1) wrong encoding on the app's side (unlikely after using more than 1 apps), or 2) an issue from the telephone operator (what might be called as "SMS relay"). FWIW, I had answered a similar issue regarding this: [Receiving Chinese blocks of texts in the Messaging app](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/159832/44325), but still not sure if this is the same case...

Comment: Very good post! @Andrew For encoding changing I need some knowledge. I will try.

Comment: I just noticed the SMS from Dropbox has a pattern, so looks like the problem is on the encoding. Could you copy and paste one of the contents from the old SMS? I want to experiment with it.

Comment: Every sma from the bank is repeatedly the aime, and for Amazon equally. It's expected to be a 6 digit number