# Why are filenames containing some emojis renamed to Chinese characers?

Tags: files, emoticons

I have a setup to transfer my files from my Windows machine to my Android phone via Syncthing. I notice that some files whose names have emojis are renamed to  strange Chinese characters:

- `C`→`ߌ⠃`
- `C`→`ߌ㠃`
- `T`→`ߌ䠔`
- `N`→`ߌ堎`

As the result in my phone they are write-protected. I'm unable to delete them:

[image]

However files whose name contains this emoji `✔️` are not affected.

Not sure if this is relevant to the problem, but for full information, when I try to remove this protection, `diskpart` doesn't detect my Android phone.

<sub>Next in line: [Why are files with wrong character encoding name write-protected?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/250608/94084)</sub>

Comment: You only have MTP access to your phone. It appears to have problems with the character set. You must deal with this on the phone itself, which is sort-of off-topic here on Super User.

Comment: The cause is possibly due to wrong character encoding (similar case: [Receiving Chinese blocks of texts in the Messaging app](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/159832/44325)). Not sure how to fix it since I'm not familiar with Syncthing though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Andrew nailed it in his [comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/249146/why-are-filenames-containing-some-emojis-renamed-to-chinese-characers#comment335211_249146). You can see a similar issue reported  between other Operating Systems and duplicate file names, here [Unicode errors while syncing between Mac OS X and Linux](https://forum.syncthing.net/t/unicode-errors-while-syncing-between-mac-os-x-and-linux/9741)

Maintainer of Syncthing [says](https://forum.syncthing.net/t/unicode-errors-while-syncing-between-mac-os-x-and-linux/9741/4)

> ... People moving files between systems have historically been stoically accepting of special characters getting mangled. Nobody in Sweden is that surprised when a file `räksmörgås` ends up being called `r‰ksmˆrgÂs`. That’s fine. But **it doesn’t work when we need to sync changes bidirectionally between systems with different encodings**...

(Emphasis supplied)

Background to the above discussion is the closure of this issue [Sync between Linux and OS X causes massive unicode errors](https://github.com/syncthing/syncthing/issues/4134#issuecomment-299487668)

Comment: do you know how to delete these files? `diskpart` doesn't detect my phone

Comment: Sorry, no idea about that