# Why are files with wrong character encoding name write-protected?

Tags: adb, delete, file-permissions, emoticons, character-encoding

I'm unable to delete the files with [wrong character encoding in names](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/249146/94084) on my phone. I plug it into my Windows PC and try to delete it in File Explorer. It says the files are write-protected:

[image]

[This guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I79JQewqs00) tells me to

```
su
restorecon -v -R /data/media
```

The output is

```
u0_a82@j1x3g:/ $ su
root@j1x3g:/ # restorecon -v -R /data/media
Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram , priority [2] , priority version is VE=SEPF_SM-J120H_5.1.1_0069
SELinux: Loaded file_contexts from /file_contexts
SELinux: Skipping restorecon_recursive(/data/media)
root@j1x3g:/ #
```

But the deletion still doesn't work. Nevertheless I can do this via adb.

Do you know why this happens?

Comment: From what OS is the first screen shot. Assuming you are trying to delete a file on an Android phone how is the PC connected to the Android phone and how do you try to access/delete he file (MTP protocol?).

Comment: Yes. I'm unable to delete it on my phone. I plug it into my Windows PC and try to delete it in Fine Explorer. Probably it is via MTP

Comment: What Windows version do you use? The dialog does not look like Windows 10 or 11. Older versions of Windows my contain bugged MTP implementations and thus fail to delete the file, or it is a general bug that affects all Windows MTP implementations. Unicode can be sometimes pretty complicated when it comes to characters that can be written as one or two characters.

Comment: It's Windows 11 though